# Getting error while syncing using ntp by running command sudo ntpd -gq

Tags: ntp

I'm getting an error while syncing using ntp by running the command
`sudo ntpd -gq`.

```
28 Sep 05:19:30 ntpd[1919]: receive: 
KoD packet from 172.19.79.12 has inconsistent xmt/org/rec timestamps.  Ignoring.
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: What did you find in a web search?

Comment: For me it happened while doing NTP client/server tests and forgot to update one of the configs, so the client attempted to synchronize to a broadcast client. (Or something like that.)

Answer (score 4):

It means your server has received the [Kiss-o-Death](https://web.archive.org/web/20191019013656/http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.1/accopt.htm)

> A client or peer receiving a kiss-of-death packet performs a set of
> sanity checks to minimize security exposure. If this is the first
> packet received from the server, the client assumes an access denied
> condition at the server. It updates the stratum and reference
> identifier peer variables and sets the access denied (test 4) bit in
> the peer flash variable. If this bit is set, the client sends no
> packets to the server. If this is not the first packet, the client
> assumes a client limit condition at the server, but does not update
> the peer variables. In either case, a message is sent to the system
> log.

Furthermore your log tells you *exactly* why it happened;

```
172.19.79.12 has inconsistent xmt/org/rec timestamps. Ignoring.
```

The time source `172.19.79.12` is broken and is being ignored. You need to check that server for further answers.

As you didn't give your `ntp.conf` file I can only presume you are using one server or peer statement. If that's the case you should take some time to read up on [ntp](http://www.ntp.org/documentation.html) to see why that's a bad thing and (like now) it breaks your timing.

Comment: It looks like the documentation moved. [Here](http://www.ntp.org/documentation.html) maybe?

Comment: @AlexisWilke looks like the old doc site is down - have changed the link to archive.org and the generic one for the doc page you linked.